# HTML file upload: is there a way to force content-type="application/octet-stream"

Tags: javascript, html

We are custom handling file uploads on the server end due to embedded limitations.

The HTML file upload code used in a Firefox browser:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="http:///192.168.1.1/upload.cgi" name="form_1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <input type="file" id="file" name="filename" content-type="application/octet-stream">
        <input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="Send">
    </form>
<body>
</html>
```

If the selected file is called "fish.jpg", the server receives its content-type as "image/jpeg". If the file is renamed to just "fish" without the file extension, the server receives its content-type as "application/octet-stream" which is what we want.

Is there a way to force "application/octet-stream" in an HTML page (with or without regular JavaScript)?

Thanks in advance,
Bert

Comment: Why? If you are going to treat any incoming data as if it was "Some bytes that might represent something but we don't know what", then why not just ignore the content type you receive instead of trying to force the browser to claim it doesn't know what it is sending?

Answer (score 6):

No. There is no `content-type="..."` attribute. You cannot influence the browser's choice of `Content-Type` header in a `multipart/form-data` subpart at all, with or without JavaScript.

Why does it matter? It's a bad idea for a server-side script do anything much with `Content-Type`, as it's so often inaccurate. Treating `image/jpeg` uploads any differently from `application/octet-stream` is something that shouldn't be done, not least because a browser may choose to upload a JPEG as `application/octet-stream` or something else (in particular, IE usually likes to send `image/pjpeg`).

If you control the server side and getting the right file upload type is critical, there should be an interface for the user to select it manually. (You can use JavaScript file extension sniffing and/or Content-Type to set a default value, but don't rely on either.)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to force
>   "application/octet-stream" in an HTML
>   page (with or without regular
>   JavaScript)?

You shouldn't set content-type in html like that. Bad guys can easily upload bypass that. The way is to do proper server-side validation.

Comment: How can you do "proper server-side validation?"